# Can't build project made with Angular CLI and SCSS

Tags: angular, sass, build

1. Created a new project with Angular CLI
2. Selected SCSS
3. Runs well on localhost with ng serve
4. Can't run build, it throws an error, only with SCSS.

Angular CLI version:

```
Angular CLI: 13.0.2
Node: 14.18.2
Package Manager: npm 6.14.15
OS: linux x64

Angular: 
... 

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1300.2 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         13.0.2 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   13.0.2 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          13.0.2 (cli-only)
```

Here is the error log:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: `$ npm cache clean --force`

Step 2: Delete node_modules by `$ rm -rf node_modules` (`rmdir /S /Q node_modules` in windows) folder or delete it manually by going into the directory and right-click > delete / move to trash. If are not updating your packages you can delete the `package-lock.json` file too.

Step 3: `npm install`

To start again,

```
$ npm start
```

This worked for me. Hopes it works for you too.

PS: Still if it is there, kindly check the error it is displaying in read and act accordingly. This error is specific to node.js environment.

Comment: I tried this,but it is still not working. The error I posted above is from the node error log, the error that shows in the console is red and the last 2 lines are : | /* harmony default export */ const __WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__ = (___CSS_LOADER_EXPORT___);